# How to detect if file path is Windows in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

My Python module runs in a Linux environment.  However, it may be given data that was generated in a Windows environment, and thus the data may contain a Windows-specific file path such as:

```
>>> raw = `c:\\alpha\\bravo\\foo.txt`
```

I can wrap that path in a `pathlib.PureWindowsPath` object, and that is useful.  I can carry on from there in an environment-independent way.

```
>>> from pathlib import PureWindowsPath
>>> pwp = PureWindowsPath( raw )
>>> pwp
PureWindowsPath('c:/alpha/bravo/foo.txt')
>>> pwp.as_posix()
'c:/alpha/bravo/foo.txt'
>>> pwp.parts
('c:\\', 'alpha', 'bravo', 'foo.txt')
>>> keep = pwp.parts[ pwp.parts.index( 'bravo' ) : ]
>>> keep
>>> ('bravo', 'foo.txt' )
```

However, how can I detect ***when*** to use a `PureWindowsPath`?

If I wrap the path in just a `pathlib.PurePath` object, it does create a derived `PurePosixPath` for that.  However, the raw path value is not interpreted in a useful way;  the directory separators are not corrected;  the path is not correctly split into parts.

```
>>> from pathlib import PurePath
>>> pp = PurePath( raw )
>>> pp
PurePosixPath('c:\\alpha\\bravo\\foo.txt')
>>> pp.as_posix()
'c:\\alpha\\bravo\\foo.txt'
>>> pp.parts
('c:\\alpha\\bravo\\foo.txt',)
```

Is there some other `pathlib` API that can automatically detect when the raw path value contains, as the documentation puts it, "semantics appropriate for" Windows?   So far, I must depend on a human to decide that for me and pass an argument to my Python module that informs me to use `PureWindowsPath`.

Documentation found:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Anyone?  Anyone?  I cannot be the only person who has has this problem.  Somebody out there may have a better answer than the kludgy alternatives I have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to ***always*** wrap the raw path value in a `PureWindowsPath` object.

That is sufficient for my needs when the path is Windows-specific, as demonstrated in the original post.

That is sufficient for my needs when the path is Linux-specific, as demonstrated below.

```
>>> from pathlib import PureWindowsPath
>>> raw = '/home/fred/alpha/bravo/foo.txt'
>>> pwp = PureWindowsPath( raw )
>>> pwp
PureWindowsPath('/home/fred/alpha/bravo/foo.txt')
>>> pwp.as_posix()
'/home/fred/alpha/bravo/foo.txt'
>>> pwp.parts
('\\', 'home', 'fred', 'alpha', 'bravo', 'foo.txt')
>>> keep = pwp.parts[ pwp.parts.index( 'bravo' ) : ]
>>> keep
('bravo', 'foo.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to ***always*** wrap the raw path value in a `PureWindowsPath` object, ***and then*** wrap the POSIX representation of that in a `PurePath` object.

That double-wrapping works better, especially when the Windows-specific path begins with drive letter.

For a Windows-specific path:

```
>>> from pathlib import PurePath, PureWindowsPath
>>> raw = 'c:\\alpha\\bravo\\foo.txt'
>>> pwp = PureWindowsPath( raw )
>>> pwp
PureWindowsPath('c:/alpha/bravo/foo.txt')
>>> pwp.parts
('c:\\', 'alpha', 'bravo', 'foo.txt')
>>> pp = PurePath( pwp.as_posix() )
>>> pp
PurePosixPath('c:/alpha/bravo/foo.txt')
>>> pp.parts
('c:', 'alpha', 'bravo', 'foo.txt')
>>> idx = pp.parts.index( 'bravo' )
>>> pp.parts[:idx]
('c:', 'alpha')
>>> pp.parts[idx:]
('bravo', 'foo.txt')
```

For a Linux-specific path:

```
>>> from pathlib import PurePath, PureWindowsPath
>>> raw = '/home/fred/alpha/bravo/foo.txt'
>>> pwp = PureWindowsPath( raw )
>>> pwp
PureWindowsPath('/home/fred/alpha/bravo/foo.txt')
>>> pwp.parts
('\\', 'home', 'fred', 'alpha', 'bravo', 'foo.txt')
>>> pp = PurePath( pwp.as_posix() )
>>> pp
PurePosixPath('/home/fred/alpha/bravo/foo.txt')
>>> pp.parts
('/', 'home', 'fred', 'alpha', 'bravo', 'foo.txt')
>>> idx = pp.parts.index( 'bravo' )
>>> pp.parts[:idx]
('/', 'home', 'fred', 'alpha')
>>> pp.parts[idx:]
('bravo', 'foo.txt')
```